# Close votes not showing up

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close

Normally, when a question has one or more votes to close, we see the number by the "close" button, as "close (3)".  I've recently noticed a couple of questions which I had voted to close, that do not display the number.

For example, see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa).  I don't see a number by the close button.  However, if I click close, I get the message "You have already voted to close this question".

Are others seeing this behavior?

Comment: I suspect close votes might time out after a while?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your close vote caused the the question to enter the [Close Votes review queue](https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/close/1063). The result of the review was that the question should be left open. As a result, your close vote "aged away" after a few days.